# Hermeneutics on "Not one stone left upon another"

Tags: prophecy, temple, olivet-discourse

There are three Scriptures that use a phrase similar to "not one stone will be left upon another". The first two are in Matthew 24:2 and Mark 13:2 and refer to the temple's destruction. The last one refers to the destruction of Jerusalem in Luke 19:44b.

In all the explanations I have read on the fulfillment of these prophecies, the temple destruction is defended as a literal interpretation. The few explanations of the city's destruction interpret it not as literal but as hyperbole.

My question is, why is this so? How do we know that **both** prophecies aren't supposed to be hyperbole, since they nearly contain the same language?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there are more places that use the phrase "stone upon another":

- Matt 24:2 - And answering, He said to them, "Do you not see all these things? Truly I say to you, no **not even a stone shall be left here upon a stone**, which will not be thrown down." [This refers to both the temple and Jerusalem.]
- Mark 13:2 - And Jesus said to him, "Do you see these great buildings? **Not one stone shall be left here upon a stone**, which shall not be thrown down." [This refers to both the temple and Jerusalem.]
- Luke 19:44 - They will level you to the ground—you and the children within your walls. They will **not leave one stone on another**, because you did not recognize the time of your visitation from God.” [This refers to Jerusalem.]
- Luke 21:6 - "As to these things which you are beholding, the days will come in which **no stone will be left upon a stone**, which will not be thrown down."  [This refers to both the temple and Jerusalem.]

All these allude to the construction of Jerusalem and the temple:

- Hag 2:15 - Now consider carefully from this day forward: Before **one stone was placed on another** in the temple of the LORD,

That is, the NT use of "not one stone upon another" is a hyperbolic allusion to the deconstruction of the temple and Jerusalem; that is, placing "one stone upon another" refers to building the temple, and "not one stone upon another" refers (hyperbolically) to the destruction of the Temple and Jerusalem.

Thus, all the NT references of "not one stone upon another" refers to the complete destruction of the buildings, hyperbolically as a few foundations stones still exist but the original buildings are definitely gone and completely destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to this question is virtually the opposite of the suggestion made in the OP, i.e. in place of both prophecies being hyperbole, both are quite literal and focused on The Temple.

The text in Luke, which addresses Jerusalem as noted in the question, reads:

> And shall lay thee even with the ground, and thy children **within thee**;
> and they shall not leave **in thee** one stone upon another; because thou
> knewest not the time of thy visitation. (Luke 19:44, KJV)
>
> καὶ ἐδαφιοῦσίν σε καὶ τὰ τέκνα σου **ἐν σοί** καὶ οὐκ ἀφήσουσιν **ἐν σοί**
> λίθον ἐπὶ λίθῳ ἀνθ ὧν οὐκ ἔγνως τὸν καιρὸν τῆς ἐπισκοπῆς σου (Luke
> 19:44, Greek TR)

As in the English translation, the Greek indicates a focus on something "in" the city.  This is a different wording than one might expect if the entire city and/or its exterior walls were being addressed.  Granted, the wording could be understood to have a broader application to all buildings and walls, but it most certainly is not forced to have such an application because the text *does not* say, for example: "...and they shall not leave **thee with** one stone upon another."  In other words, the text clearly draws the listener's mind to something *inside* the city.

The most natural object of attention within the city was its temple.  The Temple was famous.  Even Titus, the Roman general whose troops destroyed the Temple in A.D. 70, had commanded them not to touch it.  It was the place in which God had chosen to place His "name" there.

> And the LORD said unto him, I have heard thy prayer and thy
> supplication, that thou hast made before me: I have hallowed **this
> house, which thou hast built, to put my name there for ever;** and
> mine eyes and mine heart shall be there perpetually. (1 Kings 9:3,
> KJV)
>
> And unto his son will I give one tribe, that David my servant may have
> a light alway before me **in Jerusalem, the city which I have chosen
> me to put my name there.** (1 Kings 11:36, KJV)

God had chosen His house, built **in** Jerusalem, as the place to put His name.

Jesus addresses the Temple itself in speaking of the stones not being left one upon another.  His prophecy was fulfilled, literally, because one of the soldiers, attempting to force out of the temple its refuge-seekers, had cast into it a burning torch which immediately caught fire in an inextinguishable blaze.  The heat of the flames caused the gold that lined the interior walls to run into the cracks between the stones, and, forgetting their strict orders, in the frenzy to get at this gold, the soldiers overturned every stone.

Thus was Jesus' prophecy literally fulfilled, and it was fulfilled inside the city of Jerusalem.

Answer (score 1):

**Prophecy Happens!** History has a way of confirming interpretations...and exposing false interpretations. In this case, Jesus prophesied the tearing down of the Temple stone by stone within a generation of time.

**What happened?** The Temple of the Jews was torn down, stone by stone, by the Roman invading soldiers within the generation: 70 A.D.! No hyperbole involved at all. Eventually Jerusalem city was devastated and "salted over" by the Roman Legions, and Jews were forbidden to go there.

**No Possibility** There is no way a biblical scholar could consider the Destruction of the Temple to be hyperbole. The stones are in the Kidron ravine to this day as a testament to the accuracy of Jesus's prophecy. Literally fulfilled. (Check any archaeology book or documentary on Israel, or go on a trip to Israel to see personally.

Comment: Please reread the question.

Comment: This [picture of the Western Wall in Jerusalem from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Wall#/media/File:Westernwall2.jpg) suggests some stones were physically left upon others

Comment: this depends on whether one counts the outer wall of the Temple complex. But as @Dottard points out, the foundation stones remain.

Comment: @57385-The question was "how do we know that **both** weren't to be interpreted as hyperbole?" This answer showed that, _for sure_, the prophecy about the Temple was fulfilled  **literally**, with only the retaining wall on the western slope  partially remaining. Jesus's intentions were carried out by the Romans.

Comment: @raygrant I take issue with calling the result of the prophecy "Jesus's intentions."  Jesus had no such intentions.  At all.  He did, however, warn people of what was coming.

Comment: @Biblasia-It is not a pleasing thing for God to judge anyone. But as Jesus spoke in Chapter 23 of Matthew, the Jewish hierarchy _had filled up the measure of the sins...!_ and judgment was necessary...according to Jesus. He intended to see to it that the Temple would be torn down as a punishment. Chapter 23 is quite emphatic! It is true that the _foundation stones_ of the Temple Complex retaining walls are still recognizable (mostly buried underground). But **the buildings** which were the topic of discussion were all torn down! Just as Jesus said.